# What is the range of 'many hundreds of something'?

Tags: expressions

What is the range of 'many hundreds of something'?

Or, does the expression only suggest ***an indefinite, large number of something***?

Comment: Can't you say that in your language? [Life is **a** picnic}

Answer (score 3):

It is literal; "many" means a large number (so two or three is not many, but fifty might be) and hundreds is a counter. But there is a upper limit too; the speaker hasn't said "many thousands" or "many millions" so you may infer that there are *not* many millions.

So if there were 5000, that would be many hundreds, but 500 would not be many hundreds and 500000 would be many thousands.

It is, of course, fuzzy, and intended to give an impression rather than a mathematical value.